# Shading region between vertical and diagonal lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `ggplot` to shade the region between the vertical line and the diagonal line as shown below. Is there a way to do this?

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,-1), y=c(1,-1))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope=-1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit tricky, but if you know the coordinates of the area (Inf), you can use them to fill the shades using `geom_polygon` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,-1), y=c(1,-1))
upper_area <- data.frame(x=c(-Inf,0,0),y=c(Inf,Inf,0))
down_area <- data.frame(x=c(0,0,Inf),y=c(0,-Inf,-Inf))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope=-1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=x, y=y), data=upper_area, fill="red") +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=x, y=y), data=down_area, fill="blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**old answer**

It is a bit tricky, but if you know the coordinates of the area, you can use them to fill the shades using `geom_polygon` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,-1), y=c(1,-1))
upper_area <- data.frame(x=c(-1,0,0),y=c(1,1,0))
down_area <- data.frame(x=c(0,0,1),y=c(0,-1,-1))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope=-1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=x, y=y), data=upper_area, fill="red") +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=x, y=y), data=down_area, fill="blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You could probably also take account of the expansion like I did. But anyway. Nice one. +1

Comment: Thanks @stefan, Good idea to use `Inf`. Nice way of using `annotate`! +1

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use `annotate` with `geom="ribbon"`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,-1), y=c(1,-1))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  # 1.1 = 1 + default expansion of 5 % of the data range, i.e. .05 * 2 (= 1  - (-1))
  annotate(geom="ribbon", x = c(-Inf, 0), ymin = c(1.1, 0), ymax = Inf, fill = "grey45") +
  annotate(geom="ribbon", x = c(0, Inf), ymin = -Inf, ymax = c(0, -1.1), fill = "grey45") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_abline(slope=-1) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a more robust example that works with any flexible slope, intercept and axis limits.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,-1), y = c(1,-1))

slope     <- -0.5
intercept <- 0.5
limit_x   <- 4
limit_y   <- 4

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  annotate(geom = "ribbon", x = c(-Inf, intercept), ymin = c(-limit_x * slope, slope * intercept), ymax = Inf, fill = "red") +
  annotate(geom = "ribbon", x = c(intercept, Inf),  ymin = -Inf, ymax = c(slope * intercept, limit_x * slope), fill = "blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-limit_x, limit_x), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-limit_y, limit_y), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope = slope) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = intercept)
```

[image]